# backbone routes and pushstate

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, pushstate, backbone-routing

In my backbone application I trying to tidy my URLs up a little bit, I am wanting something that looks like this,

```
http://develpoment.dev/dashboard
htttp://development.dev/project/create
```

What is happening at the moment is that if I navigate too, `http://develpoment.dev/#dashboard` then the hash gets stripped out and the page loads as I would expect it too.

However if I directly access `http://develpoment.dev/dashboard` then I get a 404 page not found, this it not great for users who want to bookmark or return an URL later, have I set something up incorrectly?

Here is how I initialize my Router.

```
$(function(){
    App.Routes.Application = new App.Routes.app();
    Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
});
```

Comment: you have to update you web server configuration - all URLS at `http://develpoment.dev/` should be mapped on single page. You receive 404 as you dont have any page at `http://develpoment.dev/dashboard`

Comment: @Evgeniy - why not post as answer?

Answer (score 0):

404 is expected result as you dont have any page under `http://develpoment.dev/dashboard` URL
In case of single page application, all URLs under site domain should be mapped to one page, the bootstrap page you start application with.